# Docker container COPY source cache size

Tags: docker

I am trying to use a docker container as a build environment for my C++ app. I have seen many docker tutorials (including this one on the docker site https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) that copy the source into the image and do the build as part of the image building. I tried this and my docker build cache quickly grew to be enormous, since every time I compiled it created a new cache entry containing the whole source tree.

The alternative would be the Builder pattern (also mentioned in that article), i.e. to have a docker image with the compiler installed and set up already, but not do the compilation until the `docker run` stage, where I would bind-mount the source into the container. But this way I lose many of the benefits of multi-stage docker builds.

Am I missing something, or are people just generally not concerned with their docker cache size?

**EDIT**
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 AS builder
RUN apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends g++ ninja-build cmake && \
    apt-get clean && \
    mkdir /build    
WORKDIR /build
COPY . /src
RUN cmake -G Ninja /src && cmake --build . && cmake --install .

FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends && \
    apt-get clean
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: This isn't a problem I've run into in practice.  You can use commands like `docker system prune` to clean things up.  Usually the source tree isn't _that_ big; are you making sure your `.dockerignore` file excludes things like the object file tree from a host-based build?

Comment: @sascha I added my dockerfile. Why do you say COPY and beyond are not cached? Maybe I am looking in the wrong place? I was looking at both the size of `/var/lib/docker`, as well as at the number and size of untagged layers in `docker images -a`